# how to copy zip and other files in REST web service using java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, download, fileinputstream

Do anyone know how to copy data in zip file, jar file , binary file and others in REST web service using java? I write a web service method to copy file using FileInputStream , but it can only copy file type.

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Who's got the zip file? Is it being uploaded or downloaded? Are you extracting data from it or adding data to it? (Also, what framework are you using to help you do this?)

Comment: hi, client user will get the zip file.Acutally, zip file is aldy uploaded in user's folder. Using java io stream , i can't download zip, jar files , pictures. Any other way to do? Now, I don't use any framework. I do it in REST web service in web application. I am doing cloud storage for internship.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [apache httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/) for this.  Your code might look something like (note, make sure you're using version 4.x or higher):

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpRequestBase httpMethod = httpMethod = new HttpGet(myUrlString);
httpMethod.setHeader("Accept", "application/zip");
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpMethod);
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
if(statusCode != 200) {
    throw new Exception("Bad return status code of: "+statusCode);
}
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
if( entity != null) {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("myFile.zip");
    int nextByte=0;
    InputStream cis = entity.getContent();
    try {
        while( (nextByte = cis.read()) >= 0) fos.write(nextByte);
    } finally {
        fos.close();
        cis.close();
    }
}
```

I haven't compiled this, but you could probably get it going without too much issue (feel free to edit my comment and correct the code if you try to compile this and there are errors).  Also note, this code should generically work for downloading anything from a web request (after changing the "Accept" header).